# Help to locate a woocommerce hook method

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

We are migrating a working project from a centos server to a distributed environment in which databases, load-balancers, cache servers, and applications are on different machines.

I am trying to trace an issue in WordPress. When the user gets back from IPG, it takes quite a time to add *note* to order and it leads to a painful timeout afterward. I could trace the problem up until here:

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php

line 1723 reads:

```php
            do_action(
                'woocommerce_new_customer_note',
                array(
                    'order_id'      => $this->get_id(),
                    'customer_note' => $commentdata['comment_content'],
                ) 
            ); /* It takes forever to complete */
```

Based on my limited knowledge of WordPress, **woocommerce_new_customer_note** is a hook that fails to fulfill its goal.

I need help in:

- finding where the **woocommerce_new_customer_note** hook sits and continue my debugging.
- Finding out why this code fails to execute

Side note: We are on ubuntu 18.04, LEMP stack, PHP-FPM 7.2

Comment: Have you tried searching all your files for woocommerce_new_customer_note? WooCommerce's own actions on this hook send emails, via its background mails sender process: do you get emails generated from your site correctly? Could something be timing out trying to send an email, because it can't connect to a downstream mail server for example? But some other plugins or your theme might also hook this too, so you should search all of your files for the hook not just WooCommerce itself.

Comment: Yes I did. I was expecting to find it within the files. I don't get any emails as well. How do you know it involves with sending emails?

Comment: You'll find it here in [WC_Emails](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.1/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L102), and a related hook in [WC_Email_Customer_Note](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.1/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-note.php#L49) which is triggered by WC_Email.

Comment: Once I comment out do_action('woocommerce_new_customer_note', it works. What am I missing if I do so? just emails?